# Problem with data binding in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I'm trying to understand better how data binding works in .net. I was checking [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/327413) article, and I came up with this code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form//, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler MyTextChanged;

    [System.ComponentModel.Bindable(true)]
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set 
        {
            textBox1.Text = value;
            if (MyTextChanged != null)
                MyTextChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("MyText"));
        }
    }

    MyClass myClass { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myClass = new MyClass();
        Binding binding = new Binding("MyText", myClass, "Dic");
        binding.Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(binding_Parse);
        binding.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(binding_Format);
        DataBindings.Add(binding);
        myClass.AddStuff("uno", "UNO");
    }

    void OnMyTextChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyTextChanged != null) MyTextChanged(this, e);
    }

    void binding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value is Dictionary<string, string>)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> source = (Dictionary<string, string>)e.Value;
            e.Value = source.Count.ToString();
        }
    }

    void binding_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.DesiredType.ToString());
    }

    private void changemyClassButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myClass.AddStuff(myClass.Dic.Count.ToString(), "'" + myClass.Dic.Count.ToString() + "'");
    }

    private void changeMyTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyText = "1234";
    }
}

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Dictionary<string, string> Dic { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void AddStuff(string key, string value)
    {
        Dic.Add(key, value);
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Dic"));
    }
}
```

I'm trying to bind `MyText` to `myClass`. The problem is that the function `binding_Parse` is never being called. I know I could probably bind `textBox1.Text` directly to `myClass`, or that there might be a thousand other possible ways to do what I'm trying to do, but this is just a practice; I'm trying to understand better data binding. So I want to bind a custom object to a custom property so I can see the process from end to end. The custom object is `myClass`, and the custom property is `MyText`. I've tried all kinds of variations, like implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but I can't get `binding_Parse` to be called (I would expect it to be called when I call `changeMyTextButton_Click`). Am I missing something?

**Edit:**
To put it simpler: I want to write a user control with a property `string MyText` that then a user can bind to something else, the same way you can bind a `TextBox`'s `Text` property to something else. So I don't want to bind to the property of a control to an object, I want to write a control with a property that then a user can bind to an object.

Comment: what do you intend to do? update textbox content with MyText property? or force binding_parse to be executed?

Comment: I want to bind `MyText` to `myClass.Dic`, so that whenever `MyText` changes, `myClass.Dic` changes (to start with I want `binding_Parse` to get called, since there is where I would set the new value for `MyText`), and whenever `myClass.Dic` changes, `MyText` changes (this already works). I choosed to set `MyText` to `myClass.Dic.Count.ToString()` when myClass.Dic changes for no particular reason. I just want to see any change on one reflected on another. I found [this][1] article, but it's for WFP. I can't find one for Windows Forms.

[1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx

Comment: Another example would be to bind `string str1` to `string str2` so that whenever `str1` changes, `str2` is set to `str1` backwards, and whenever `str2` changes, `str1` is set to `str2` backwards. All by using standard .net data binding. This would force me to use Format and Parse, and I could finally see how the whole data binding cycle works.

Comment: Just edited my question. Hope is clearer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I figured it out in case anyone had the same problem. I had to create an event handler named `MyTextChanged` to let the `Binding` knows `MyText` is changing, and set the `Binding`s `DataSourceUpdateMode` property to `OnPropertyChanged`. Using this simple principle I can bind a pixel in my screen to the rest of the universe :). Here's the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler MyTextChanged;

    [Bindable(true)]
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return textBox1.Text; }
        set 
        {
            if (textBox1.Text != value)
            {
                textBox1.Text = value;
                OnMyTextChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    MyClass myClass { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myClass = new MyClass();
        Binding binding = new Binding("MyText", myClass, "Dic");
        binding.DataSourceUpdateMode = DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged;
        binding.Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(binding_Parse);
        binding.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(binding_Format);
        DataBindings.Add(binding);
        myClass.AddStuff("uno", "UNO");
    }

    void OnMyTextChanged()
    {
        if (MyTextChanged != null) MyTextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    void binding_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Value is Dictionary<string, string>)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> source = (Dictionary<string, string>)e.Value;
            e.Value = source.Count.ToString();
        }
    }

    void binding_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.DesiredType.ToString());

    }

    private void changemyClassButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myClass.AddStuff(myClass.Dic.Count.ToString(), "'" + myClass.Dic.Count.ToString() + "'");
    }

    private void changeMyTextButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MyText = "1234";
    }
}

public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Dictionary<string, string> Dic { get; set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        Dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public void AddStuff(string key, string value)
    {
        Dic.Add(key, value);
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Dic"));
    }
}
```

Comment: What I still don't understand is why is this not causing and infinite recursion. I guess there is some internal mechanism to prevent that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help you out, understanding when Parse event is executed.

To see binding_Parse working check out this sample:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public MyClass myClass { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.AddStuff("uno", "UNO");

        Binding b = new Binding("Text", myClass, "Dic");
        b.Parse += new ConvertEventHandler(b_Parse);
        b.Format += new ConvertEventHandler(b_Format);
        textBox1.DataBindings.Add(b);
    }

    void b_Format(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Value = (e.Value as Dictionary<string, string>)["uno"].ToString();
        textBox1.Text = e.Value.ToString();
    }

    void b_Parse(object sender, ConvertEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("This is executed when you lost focus\n\nI'm parsing your entered text: " + e.Value);
    }


}
```

You just have debug. Click on the button, and notice Format event is called first.
Then if you manually change textbox1.Text value, when you click on the button again, there will be a lost focus, and then Parse event will be executed.

To create your custom control also check [this site](http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_user_controls.html).

Comment: Please see my edit. I apologize for the confusion. Hope you can still help me.

Comment: Ok did you see the site I told you?

Comment: I did but I couldn't find anything about binding properties; they use events instead.